# Trouble creating a java loop to loop based on yes or no input

Tags: java, loops

I just need it so that after it computes, it prompts the user to input "y" or "Y" for the program to loop with new values and "n" or "N" to end the program. That's the only thing that I need, the rest of the code worked fine. The code is meant to have the user input 2 integer values and 2 double values, and then add, subtract, multiply and divide them.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int intNum1, intNum2; //creates two integer variables
        
        double dblNum1, dblNum2; //creates two double variables
        
        
        System.out.printf("Input integer value 1: "); //prompt to input first integer value
        intNum1 = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.printf("Input integer value 2: "); //prompt to input second integer value
        intNum2 = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.printf("Input double value 1: "); //prompt to input first double value
        dblNum1 = input.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.printf("Input double value 2: "); //prompt to input second double values
        dblNum2 = input.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.printf("\nInteger output: "); //prompt to display the integer outputs
        
        System.out.printf("\nAdding %d and %d = %d", intNum1, intNum2, (intNum1 + intNum2)); //computes and prints sum of first two integer values
        
        if(intNum1 > intNum2) {   //checks to see if the first integer value is greater than the second integer value in order to perform subtraction
        System.out.printf("\nSubtraction %d and %d = %d", intNum1, intNum2, (intNum1 - intNum2)); //computes and then prints the subtraction of the two integer values based on the first value being greater
        }
        if(intNum1 < intNum2) { //checks to see if the second integer value is greater than the first integer value
        System.out.printf("\nSubtraction %d and %d = %d", intNum1, intNum2, (intNum2 - intNum1)); //computes and then prints the subtraction of the two integer values based on the second value being greater
        }
    
        if (intNum1 == intNum2) { //checks if both numbers are equal
            System.out.printf("\nSubstacting a number from itself gives you zero"); //prints a message for when both integer values are equal
        }
        
        if (intNum1 > intNum2) { //checks to see that the two integer values are not equal
            System.out.printf("\nMultiplying %d and %d = %d", intNum1, intNum2, (intNum1 * intNum2)); //performs and prints the product of multiplying the two integer values
        }
        if (intNum1 < intNum2) { //checks to see that the two integer values are not equal
            System.out.printf("\nMultiplying %d and %d = %d", intNum1, intNum2, (intNum1 * intNum2)); //performs and prints the product of multiplying the two integer values
        }
        
        if (intNum1 == intNum2) { //checks to see if the two integer values are equal
            System.out.printf("\nSquaring %d = %d", intNum1,  (intNum1 * intNum2)); //performs and prints the squaring of the two integer values
        }
        if (intNum2 != 0) { // verifies that the second integer value is not 0
             System.out.printf("\nDividing %d and %d = %d", intNum1, intNum2, (intNum1 / intNum2)); //performs and prints the quotient of the two integer values
        }
        if (intNum2 != 0) { // verifies that the second integer value is not 0
            System.out.printf("\nModing %d and %d = %d", intNum1, intNum2, (intNum1 % intNum2)); //performs and prints the mod of the first integer values
        }
        if (intNum2 == 0) { //verifies that the second integer value is 0
            System.out.printf("\nError: You cannot divide or mod by 0."); //prints error message if the second integer value is 0
        }
        System.out.printf("\n\nDouble output: "); //prompt to display the double outputs
        
        System.out.printf("\nAdding %.2f and %.2f = %.2f", dblNum1, dblNum2, (dblNum1 + dblNum2)); //computes and prints sum of first two double values
        
        if(dblNum1 > dblNum2) {   //checks to see if the first double value is greater than the second double value in order to perform subtraction
        System.out.printf("\nSubtraction %.2f and %.2f = %.2f", dblNum1, dblNum2, (dblNum1 - dblNum2)); //computes and then prints the subtraction of the two double values based on the first value being greater
        }
        if(dblNum1 < dblNum2) { //checks to see if the second double value is greater than the first double value
        System.out.printf("\nSubtraction %.2f and %.2f = %.2f", dblNum1, dblNum2, (dblNum2 - dblNum1)); //computes and then prints the subtraction of the two double values based on the second value being greater
        }
    
        if (dblNum1 == dblNum2) { //checks if both numbers are equal
            System.out.printf("\nSubstacting a number from itself gives you zero"); //prints a message for when both double values are equal
        }
        
        if (dblNum1 > dblNum2) { //checks to see that the two double values are not equal
            System.out.printf("\nMultiplying %.2f and %.2f = %.2f", dblNum1, dblNum2, (dblNum1 * dblNum2)); //performs and prints the product of multiplying the two double values
        }
        if (dblNum1 < dblNum2) { //checks to see that the two double values are not equal
            System.out.printf("\nMultiplying %.2f and %.2f = %.2f", dblNum1, dblNum2, (dblNum1 * dblNum2)); //performs and prints the product of multiplying the two double values
        }
        
        if (dblNum1 == dblNum2) { //checks to see if the two double values are equal
            System.out.printf("\nSquaring %.2f = %.2f", dblNum1,  (dblNum1 * dblNum2)); //performs and prints the squaring of the two double values
        }
        if (dblNum2 != 0) { // verifies that the second double value is not 0
             System.out.printf("\nDividing %.2f and %.2f = %.2f", dblNum1, dblNum2, (dblNum1 / dblNum2)); //performs and prints the quotient of the two double values
        }
        if (dblNum2 != 0) { // verifies that the second double value is not 0
            System.out.printf("\nModing %.2f and %.2f = %.2f", dblNum1, dblNum2, (dblNum1 % dblNum2)); //performs and prints the mod of the first double values
        }
        if (dblNum2 == 0) { //verifies that the second double value is 0
            System.out.printf("\nError: You cannot divide or mod by 0."); //prints error message if the second double value is 0
        
        System.out.println("Would you continue press 'Y or y' or quit press 'N or n'");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, ask the user. You already know how, you're asking hte user for doubles and ints and all that all the time.

To ask for some text, you use `input.next()`. This will return a string. To check if it is "Y" or "y" (strings are case sensitive), you'd invoke `equalsIgnoreCase("Y")` on it. (Don't do `input.next() == "Y"` - you don't compare strings with `==`, but with `.equals` or `.equalsIgnoreCase`.

NB: `next()` will give you one 'word', up to the next space. If you'd rather get everything until they hit enter, the fix is to initialize your scanner. After creating it (`new Scanner`), tell it how you want things to be delimited. `input.useDelimiter("\r?\n");` tells it that tokens are separated by enter presses (vs any whitespace); usually you want to do that to all your scanners.

Answer (score 0):

Place all your code within the **main()** method (with the exception of the Scanner declaration) into a **while** loop:

```
String yn = "y"; 
while (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) { 

    // all your code up to the end of all your IF statements...

    // WHILE loop for the "Would you like to continue" prompt...
    yn = "";
    while (yn.isEmpty()) { 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Would you like to continue? (y/n): --> ");
        yn = input.next();
        if (!yn.matches("(?i)[yn]{1}")) {
            System.out.println("Invalid response provided (" + yn + ")! Try again...");
            yn = "";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(yn.toUpperCase() + " was provided.");
    System.out.println();
}
```